# how may i select the time interval from last month ?, and it must also be between 1pm from last day of the last month till midday of the actual day

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few hours , so far what i have reached is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE(datetime_column) 
  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%M-01'),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
    AND HOUR(datetime_column) > = '13'
     ORDER BY
         datetime_column
```

Besides the day interval, i also need the hour interval which must be between 13h pm from last day of the last month till midday for present date.

The fiddle doesnt seem to work with the current query but its working in my database, but check fiddle for more info:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a3jui7aPMevU81Cka4BqXg/0

And sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable  (
  id INT,
  datetime_column DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO mytable (id,datetime_column) VALUES 
(1,'2020-03-31 08:00:00'),
(2,'2020-03-31 13:00:00'),
(3,'2020-04-02 14:30:00'),
(4,'2020-04-06 18:00:00'),
(5,'2020-04-21 05:00:00'),
(6,'2020-04-23 13:00:00'),
(7,'2020-04-23 14:00:00');
```

If more info is necessary please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this what you want

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (
          DATE(datetime_column) > LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      AND datetime_column < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
      )
OR (
         DATE(datetime_column) = LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND  HOUR(datetime_column) >= 13
);

+------+---------------------+
| id   | datetime_column     |
+------+---------------------+
|    2 | 2020-03-31 13:00:00 |
|    3 | 2020-04-02 14:30:00 |
|    4 | 2020-04-06 18:00:00 |
|    5 | 2020-04-21 05:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Here `LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` gives the last day of previous month.

And `datetime_column < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR)` tests if that time is before mid day of today.

Comment: pretty close but i also need it to return the ids 2 and 5 ,filtering by datetime_column. thats where i got stuck. If u need further explanation about the issue, i kindly ask you to message me, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for yout time and help! :D